# Can you identify the font used in this CAPTCHA please?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

Can you please help me identify this font?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: "Less annoying than most CAPTCHAs."

Comment: Those images are being blocked by my internet security software because the site they're on is supposedly infected with a malware script called "Mal/HTMLGen-A".

Comment: http://postimg.org/ is the domain. I don't think it is a spam domain. Something is wrong with your internet security software

Comment: That's a very bizarre CAPTCHA. The intent of a CAPTCHA is to not be machine readable, yet they are using a typeface that is very kind to OCR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [Monaco](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco_%28typeface%29) to me. It's a monospaced font that comes with Macs. The slash through the zero is a distinctive feature, as are the angles on the bowls of the 'd', 'b', and 'a' characters.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this font through this nifty font finding web tool.  It came back with:

Good Pro Book Italic

Appears to be a pretty close match.  If you're ever in need of a font, give this web-app a whirl: http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: The numbers are quite different ([example](http://www.fontshop.com/fonts/downloads/fontfont/ff_good_pro_collection/)), but definitely a very nice font!